# Remove duplicate from reddit author python

Tags: python, reddit

I am trying to remove duplicate names from a list of author's comments in reddit.

This is what I've tried by now:

```
author_no_duplicates = []
author_list = []
for comment in submission.comments.list():
    author_list = comment.author
    for i in author_list:
        if i not in author_no_duplicates:
            author_no_duplicates.append(i)

for i in author_no_duplicates:
    print str(i)
```

This gives me the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/home/wizard/PycharmProjects/reddit/python/demo.py", line 71, in 
>       for i in author_list:
>       TypeError: 'Redditor' object is not iterable

Any hints?

Comment: It looks as if your `author_list` object is being set as type `Redditor`, rather than as a type that is iterable such as a `List`.

Comment: You should clarify what ```comment.author``` is as this is not iterable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in author_list:
TypeError: 'Redditor' object is not iterable
```

As the error says 'Redditor' object is not iterable
As one comment can only have one Author. So it is just one object.

you need to do this:

```
all_authors = set()
for comment in submission.comments.list():
    all_authors.add(comment.author.name)
```

This can be done in one line as:

```
unique_authors = set([comment.author.name for comment in submission.comments.list()])
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a set:

```
author_no_duplicates = list(set(author_list))
```

Comment: I've tried this at first, but I have the same error